# custom validation in laravel

Tags: php, forms, validation, laravel

I am integrating Amazon MWS in Laravel, so far so good, Now, in my dashboard, I have created a form where user can put his Seller ID and Auth Token ( provided by Amazon). My code looks like this

```
$store = StoreController::Find($id)->first();

$this->validate($request, [
'name'          => 'required|max:255',
'merchantId'    => 'required|max:255',
'authToken'     => 'required|max:255',
'marketplaceId' => 'required|max:255',
]);
 $mws    = new mwsController();
$result = $mws->checkCredentials($store);

if ($result) {
//credentials OK, Force Fill in database
//OK with it
// ALSO, I want to disable future Form Edits, any idea?
}else{
//return error on form, saying Merchant ID and Auth Token pair is invalid
//stuck at this point
//documentation doesnt help
}
```

1: Problem 1:
How can I return custom error as I commented in Code

2: I want to disable future edits in Form If Credentials Ok

**Explanation**

Once I have validated credentials, and updated it Database, I want that user can see the form, but he can not edit Auth Token , Merchant ID or any other field in the form.

Any guide line and help is highly appreciated
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would keep your validation in the validate method. That way your error response will work out of the box. How to extend the validator is explained here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/validation#custom-validation-rules

It could look something like this:

```
Validator::extend('mwsToken', function($attribute, $value, $parameters)
{
    // check if the token is valid an return result
});
```

And then you can just use it in your controller:

```
$this->validate($request, [
'name'          => 'required|max:255',
'merchantId'    => 'required|max:255',
'authToken'     => 'required|max:255|mwsToken',
'marketplaceId' => 'required|max:255',
]);
```

No need for the if/else anymore. You can just assume the token is valid there, since validation already passed. And error reporting will work automatically if you set up your Validator correctly.

---

As for the second question, not really sure what you mean. If you do not want to allow edits in certain cases, just don't render the form. Something like this perhaps (in your controller):

```
public function getEdit($id) {
   $model = Model::findOrFail($id);

   if ($model ->hasPropertyThatMeansNoEdit()) {
      abort(403);
   }

   // build and render edit form
}
```

Don't forget to do something similar in your `post` handler. Always assume the user is malicious. It isn't because there is no form, that a POST request can't be made, ie. by manipulating the request of a different model.

---

One last side note on your architecture. I noticed in your snippet you are calling your controllers directly (`StoreController`, `mwsController`). I don't think you should be doing that. Controllers are there to handle your requests, and nothing else. If you have reusable blocks of code in them, consider moving that code to a Service or a Command, and calling that command from inside your controller. It will make your controllers a lot cleaner (SRP) and makes it easier to reuse those Commands later in ie. an API or a Queue Job or something like that.

Comment: I like how you pointed out that the application logic is a bit wobbly. The first line `$store = StoreController::Find($id)->first();` also contains model logic for a controller.

Comment: Reading your answer again and again to grasp the last para.. I do believe I Shoud have it as a Service, but the same controller fetches data for user on user request, sends to model and fetches from model and routes it to views, in that case , what would you suggest? Also, please clearify SRP,not getting it exactly

Comment: Let's stick with the question(s) here, and not elaborate to much on my side note. Feel free to post the code on [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) though and drop the link here, I'll be happy to take a closer look and give you some pointers. (SRP stand for Single Responsibility Principle btw)

Comment: As for the edit, if you do not want the users to edit the credentials anymore, you are not really needing a form, are you? Just show them the information on a dedicated route / view. And in stead of aborting like I did in my answer, you could just redirect to that dedicated view in stead.

Comment: that's a cleaner approach, same as @JasonK was pointing, really glad, both answers are great and still, I can chose for one.not sure whom to chose :(

Comment: pick me, pick me! :-P JK, as usual there is no silver bullet here. Both solutions are valid. Mine is perhaps a bit cleaner, while @JasonK solution is a bit more pragmatic and easier to implement. It all depends on your scope / budget. And you do not need to accept (yet), perhaps Taylor himself will give you an even better solution ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your first question is pointed out in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/master/validation): simply add a message bag to the response. Also check out the beginner tutorial video's (by Jeffrey Wade) on Laracast, they are really helpful. The code would be:

```
public function store(Request $request, $id)
{
    // ...

    $this->validate($request, [
        'name'          => 'required|string|max:255',
        'merchantId'    => 'required|integer|max:255',
        'authToken'     => 'required|string|max:255',
        'marketplaceId' => 'required|integer|max:255',
    ]);

    $mws = new mwsController();
    if ($mws->checkCredentials($store)) {
        // Your code here
        return redirect('home')->with(['success' => 'Everything OK']); // Flash session
    }

    return redirect('home')->withErrors(['Merchant ID and Auth Token pair is invalid']); // Error bag
}
```

And to display:

```
@if (session('success'))
    <div class="positive message">{{ session('success') }}</div>
@endif

@if (count($errors) > 0)
    <div class="negative message">{{ $errors->first() }}</div>
@endif
```

You're second question is pretty hard to answer since you've given no code or example to work with. Maybe I'm not understanding the question, but I think you are looking for [middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/master/middleware).

**Edit:** To answer the second question, add a column named 'validated' (default **0**) in your database table. If the credentials are OK, update that column and set it to **1**. Use that variable in your template to manipulate the form fields, for instance:

```
<input type="text" name="merchantId" {{ $validated ? '' : 'disabled' }}/>
```

Comment: You approrach is simpler but I do have an ajax call here, so redirect may be not a good option here for me, +1 for your help bro

Comment: your edited answer will disable one field ( or all fields when applied), but still, form will be uselessly submitted

Comment: Then don't show the form (or even the page?) at all to the user. Just display it's credentials once he's authenticated.

Comment: was thinking either not to show the form or disable inputs and submit button

Comment: That's fine. Just make sure that you also check it on the server side (!). The client could still make POST requests with or without a form. Also for AJAX calls please check my answer on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37690068/laravel-refresh-data-after-ajax/37690655#37690655