# Laravel 5.5 send data to view without reloading page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

In my view I have some data that I can use `$data` in this `$data` are several other arrays with a key. Now my goal is to when a user selects something from a dropdown I want to update this `$data` array without doing a redirect.

I am aware I need to use AJAX and my AJAX call works fine I am just a tad confused on what I am supposed to do in my controller method I need to do something like this but without refreshing the page but this would remove all my other data that is already in the $data array from before

This is my method:

```
/**
 * Fetches a company 
 *
 * @param $companyId
 */
public function fetchCompany($companyId)
{
    $company = Company::where('id', $companyId)->first();

    $data['company'] = $company;

    return view('this should be the same view that I did my ajax call from', ['data' => $data]);
}
```

So I want to add this `$company` to the already existing `$data` array that I am using in my view.

Comment: maybe this post can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37690068/laravel-refresh-data-after-ajax

Comment: @LorenzoBerti I don't see how that post applies to my problem. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

Answering from what I have understand so far.

```
public function fetchCompany($companyId)
{
    $company = Company::where('id', $companyId)->first();
    return response()->json($company);
}
```

then you need to call ajax like this

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("whatever your dropdown id").change(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    url:'yoururl',
                    type: 'whatever datatype',
                    dataType:'json',
                    success: function(data){
                        var x;
                        for(x in data){
                            $("#div1").append(data[x]);
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: `#div1` is the location where you want to load your data and `var x` is just for the loop you can use for loop like this `for(var x in data)` also

Comment: But I don't want to load in this data into a div. I need to update my `$data` that I am already using in other parts of my view.

Comment: I need to do something like `$data['company'] = $company` and `return view('sameview', ['data' => $data]);`

Comment: yeah ´$companyId` varies on what I've select in the dropdown but I already query the right `$company` I just need to get it with my other data

Comment: Is the response data suppose to replace existing company record or append it to the page with existing list of initially loaded records?

Comment: hey please accept the answer if it was helpful to you thanks :)