# Refresh foreach loop data after AJAX success in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I want to refresh foreach loop data whenever I delete a license key using AJAX. The delete part is working already. The only problem now is that, it doesn't update the data in my foreach loop. I've try searching for an answer to this problem and I found this "[Laravel refresh data after ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37690068/laravel-refresh-data-after-ajax/37690655)". I've tried following the steps here but I can't seem to make it work.

**partials/licenses_loop.blade.php**

```
<div class="white-box">
        <h3 class="box-title">All Licenses <span class="pull-right">{{ $licenses->count() }}</span></h3>
        <hr>
            <p>Assigned <span class="pull-right">{{ $licenses_is_assigned->count() }}</span></p>
            <p>Unassigned <span class="pull-right">{{ $licenses_not_assigned->count() }}</span></p>
        <br>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info waves-effect waves-light" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#detailedViewModal" style="width: 100%;">Detailed View</button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal fade" id="detailedViewModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="detailedModalLabel">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="detailedModalLabel">Detailed View</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                        <table id="detailedViewTable" class="table">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Product</th>
                                    <th>Licenses</th>
                                    <th>Assigned</th>
                                    <th>Unassigned</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                @foreach ($licenses_container as $product_name => $license_counts)
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>{{ $product_name }}</td>
                                        <td>{{ $license_counts['assigned'] + $license_counts['unassigned'] }}</td>
                                        <td>{{ $license_counts['assigned'] }}</td>
                                        <td>{{ $license_counts['unassigned'] }}</td>
                                    </tr>
                                @endforeach
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**LicenseController.php**

```
public function ajax(Request $request)
    {
        $html = view('partials.licenses_loop', compact('view'))->render();

        return response()->json(compact('html'));
    }
```

**license.js**

```
function confirm_delete(id, element) {
    swal({   
        title: "Are you sure?",   
        text: "You will not be able to recover this license",  
        type: "warning",
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",   
        confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",   
        closeOnConfirm: false
     }, function(){
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });
        $.ajax({
            url: "/tango/licenses/delete/" + id,
            type: 'DELETE',
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) 
            {
                swal({   
                    title: "Deleted!",   
                    text:  "License has been successfully deleted.",
                    timer: 2000,
                        type: "success",
                        showConfirmButton: true
                });
                $(element).parents('tr').hide(1000);
                renderTable();
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, status, error) 
            {
                console.log(status + ": " + error);
            }
        });
    });
}

function renderTable() {
    var $request = $.get('licenses'); // make request
    var $container = $('.license-count-container');

    $request.done(function(data) { // success
        $container.html(data.html);
    });
}
```

**routes/web.php**

```
Route::post('/tango/licenses', 'LicenseController@ajax');
```

**licenses.blade.php**

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-sm-5 license-count-container">
            @include('partials.licenses_loop')
        </div>
```

Comment: have you tried `location.reload();`

Answer (score 0):

In your Javascript you are using `$.get` to perform a GET request. However, on your route file, you are stating that it is a POST route through `Route::post`. I guess that the server request is returning a `405: Method not allowed` and then the server action is never performed.